# How could I go about making this form?

Tags: html, forms

How could i make a form where everything is seperate from each other in html?

I was trying to make a form like the image and everything was unaligned.

[what i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5LJY.png)

[what i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLuQV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can Wrap each of the radio buttons in a label element and use CSS to make those labels take up 100% of the table cell (or whatever). Here is the example that I wrote. Hope this helps you.

```css
.st {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.st-header_corner {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1b1b;
  border-right: 1px solid #1c1b1b;
}
.st-header_row {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  background: lighten(#ddd, 10%);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #1c1b1b;
}
.st-header_col {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  background: lighten(#ddd, 10%);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1b1b;
}
.st-cell_basic {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.st-cell_plus {
  border: 1px solid darken(#ddd, 10%);
  background: #ddd;
}

.st-Radio:not([disabled]){
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}
.st-Radio:not([disabled]):hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px green;
  outline: 4px solid green;
}

.st-Radio:not([disabled]):checked+span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: green;
  padding: 0px; 
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;  
}
```

```html
<table class="st">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="st-header_corner">NAME</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">Option 1</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">Option 2</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">Option 3</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">Option 4</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">No Option</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="st-headerV">Person 1</th>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3030" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3030" data-option-position="2"><label for="3030"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3130" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3130" data-option-position="2"><label for="3130"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3230" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3230" data-option-position="2"><label for="3230"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3330" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3330" data-option-position="2"><label for="3330"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3430" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3430" data-option-position="2"><label for="3430"><span></span></label></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="st-headerV">Person 2</th>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3032" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3032" data-option-position="2"><label for="3032"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3132" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3132" data-option-position="2"><label for="3132"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3232" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3232" data-option-position="2"><label for="3232"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3332" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3332" data-option-position="2"><label for="3332"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3432" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3432" data-option-position="2"><label for="3432"><span></span></label></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="st-headerV">Person 3</th>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3034" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3034" data-option-position="2"><label for="3034"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3134" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3134" data-option-position="2"><label for="3134"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3234" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3234" data-option-position="2"><label for="3234"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3334" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3334" data-option-position="2"><label for="3334"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3434" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3434" data-option-position="2"><label for="3434"><span></span></label></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="st-headerV">Person 4</th>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3236" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3236" data-option-position="2"><label for="3236"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3336" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3336" data-option-position="2"><label for="3336"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3436" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3436" data-option-position="2"><label for="3436"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3636" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3636" data-option-position="2"><label for="3636"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3836" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3836" data-option-position="2"><label for="3836"><span></span></label></label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```